# how to inherit account_new_no_password.html in magento 2

Tags: email-templates, knockoutjs, magento2.4, guest-checkout, inheritance

I have tried this:

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
          'Magento_Payment/template/payment/cc-form.html': 
              'Namespace_Module/template/payment/cc-form.html'
        }
  }
};
```

Comment: please add `cc-form.html` and `requirejs-config.js` file path

Comment: js/requirejs-config.js

Comment: if you add full path it will be helpful others to answer!